# Create a newly unique id in android AWS

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, unique-id

So I am trying to create a new table in AWS dynamoDB, but I cannot find anywhere in the documentation that shows how to create a unique ID for android.  They show how to get the user cognito ID: `AWSMobileClient.defaultMobileClient().getIdentityManager().getCachedUserID()`, But I am not creating a new user here, I am creating a new Group, so I want a completely unique ID for every table that I create.  Does anyone know how I can do this?  I have scoured the internet for this but can't seem to find the answer.  The answer in objective-c is very simple, which is found using this: `[AWSIdentityManager defaultIdentityManager].identityId;`, please tell me there is something like this for the android version.  Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Had to go into my GroupsDO model and add @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey above the groupId section, and it would automatically generate a unique id on save.